# Lerping between blue and green produces grey? Unity, 2d Sprite.colour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I'm having **trouble to mix 2 colour on touching sprites**  (when blue and yellow makes grey )
To lerp or not to lerp....

**Combinations that work:**

Yellow and red = produces orange

Blue and red = produces purple.

**Blue and yellow produces grey**

if interpolated colour is not the best way to mix colour to accurately reflect the kind of mixing we would do on a colour-wheel ... then what is the correct way?

```
SpriteRenderer tempCol01 = collidedColour.mainColourGO.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
tempCol01.color = Color32.Lerp(col01, col02, 0.5f);
```

--------------------------------Second attempt------------------------------

//next I have also tried as suggested by vislila (thanks dude) 
(now mixes blue and yellow) but still doesn't mix some other colours correctly... win some lose some ;)

//New Code using HSBColor.Lerp....

```
SpriteRenderer tempCol01 = collidedColour.mainColourGO.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            tempCol01.color = Slerp(col01, col02, 0.5f);




public static Color Slerp(Color a, Color b, float t)
    {
        return (HSBColor.Lerp(HSBColor.FromColor(a), HSBColor.FromColor(b), t)).ToColor();
    }
```

**Am a bit nubie - so maybe im doing it wrong?**

//link to scripts 
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Colorx

download: 
HSBColor.unityPackage.zip‎
"helper function to tie in with HSBColor that will let you slerp between two Unity Colors. The slerp function provides much more pleasing visual results than Color.Lerp"

Comment: Use HSL color space

Comment: [Blue is Anti-Yellow](http://dawnsbrain.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/rgb-color-wheel-lg.jpg). You'd have the same problem going from Cyan to Red or Magenta to Green. Hence why you lerp the H in HSV.

Comment: What are some colors that aren't mixing correctly using `HSBColor.Lerp`? @ me when you reply so I get a notification or comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful `HSBColor` struct on the [unity wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=HSBColor#C.23_-_HSBColor.cs) that handles lerping in HSV/HSB space:

With it, you can lerp between two `Color`s in HSB space:

```
public Color LerpViaHSB(Color a, Color b, float t)
{
     return HSBColor.Lerp(HSBColor.FromColor(a), HSBColor.FromColor(b), t).ToColor();
}
```

Here's the `HSBColor` struct as shown on the unity wiki:

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public struct HSBColor
{
    public float h;
    public float s;
    public float b;
    public float a;

    public HSBColor(float h, float s, float b, float a)
    {
        this.h = h;
        this.s = s;
        this.b = b;
        this.a = a;
    }

    public HSBColor(float h, float s, float b)
    {
        this.h = h;
        this.s = s;
        this.b = b;
        this.a = 1f;
    }

    public HSBColor(Color col)
    {
        HSBColor temp = FromColor(col);
        h = temp.h;
        s = temp.s;
        b = temp.b;
        a = temp.a;
    }

    public static HSBColor FromColor(Color color)
    {
        HSBColor ret = new HSBColor(0f, 0f, 0f, color.a);

        float r = color.r;
        float g = color.g;
        float b = color.b;

        float max = Mathf.Max(r, Mathf.Max(g, b));

        if (max <= 0)
        {
            return ret;
        }

        float min = Mathf.Min(r, Mathf.Min(g, b));
        float dif = max - min;

        if (max > min)
        {
            if (g == max)
            {
                ret.h = (b - r) / dif * 60f + 120f;
            }
            else if (b == max)
            {
                ret.h = (r - g) / dif * 60f + 240f;
            }
            else if (b > g)
            {
                ret.h = (g - b) / dif * 60f + 360f;
            }
            else
            {
                ret.h = (g - b) / dif * 60f;
            }
            if (ret.h < 0)
            {
                ret.h = ret.h + 360f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ret.h = 0;
        }

        ret.h *= 1f / 360f;
        ret.s = (dif / max) * 1f;
        ret.b = max;

        return ret;
    }

    public static Color ToColor(HSBColor hsbColor)
    {
        float r = hsbColor.b;
        float g = hsbColor.b;
        float b = hsbColor.b;
        if (hsbColor.s != 0)
        {
            float max = hsbColor.b;
            float dif = hsbColor.b * hsbColor.s;
            float min = hsbColor.b - dif;

            float h = hsbColor.h * 360f;

            if (h < 60f)
            {
                r = max;
                g = h * dif / 60f + min;
                b = min;
            }
            else if (h < 120f)
            {
                r = -(h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
                g = max;
                b = min;
            }
            else if (h < 180f)
            {
                r = min;
                g = max;
                b = (h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
            }
            else if (h < 240f)
            {
                r = min;
                g = -(h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                b = max;
            }
            else if (h < 300f)
            {
                r = (h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                g = min;
                b = max;
            }
            else if (h <= 360f)
            {
                r = max;
                g = min;
                b = -(h - 360f) * dif / 60 + min;
            }
            else
            {
                r = 0;
                g = 0;
                b = 0;
            }
        }

        return new Color(Mathf.Clamp01(r),Mathf.Clamp01(g),Mathf.Clamp01(b),hsbColor.a);
    }

    public Color ToColor()
    {
        return ToColor(this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "H:" + h + " S:" + s + " B:" + b;
    }

    public static HSBColor Lerp(HSBColor a, HSBColor b, float t)
    {
        float h,s;

        //check special case black (color.b==0): interpolate neither hue nor saturation!
        //check special case grey (color.s==0): don't interpolate hue!
        if(a.b==0){
            h=b.h;
            s=b.s;
        }else if(b.b==0){
            h=a.h;
            s=a.s;
        }else{
            if(a.s==0){
                h=b.h;
            }else if(b.s==0){
                h=a.h;
            }else{
                // works around bug with LerpAngle
                float angle = Mathf.LerpAngle(a.h * 360f, b.h * 360f, t);
                while (angle < 0f)
                    angle += 360f;
                while (angle > 360f)
                    angle -= 360f;
                h=angle/360f;
            }
            s=Mathf.Lerp(a.s,b.s,t);
        }
        return new HSBColor(h, s, Mathf.Lerp(a.b, b.b, t), Mathf.Lerp(a.a, b.a, t));
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        HSBColor color;

        color = new HSBColor(Color.red);
        Debug.Log("red: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(Color.green);
        Debug.Log("green: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(Color.blue);
        Debug.Log("blue: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(Color.grey);
        Debug.Log("grey: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(Color.white);
        Debug.Log("white: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(new Color(0.4f, 1f, 0.84f, 1f));
        Debug.Log("0.4, 1f, 0.84: " + color);

        Debug.Log("164,82,84   .... 0.643137f, 0.321568f, 0.329411f  :" + ToColor(new HSBColor(new Color(0.643137f, 0.321568f, 0.329411f))));
    }
}
```